# How to check file permissions in Java (OS independently)

Tags: java, file-permissions

I have the following snippet of code:

```
public class ExampleClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String filePath = args[0];
    File file = new File(filePath);

    if (!file.exists())
        throw new FileNotFoundException();

    if (file.canWrite())
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + ": CAN WRITE!!!");
    else
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + ": CANNOT WRITE!!!!!");

    if (file.canRead())
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + ": CAN READ!!!");
    else
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + ": CANNOT READ!!!!!");

    if (file.canExecute())
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + ": CAN EXECUTE!!!");
    else
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + ": CANNOT EXECUTE!!!!!");
}
}
```

It works in Linux OS, but the problem is that it doesn't work in windows7. So the question is: Does anybody know a method to check privileges to a file in Java OS INDEPENDENTLY?

Comment: How does it "not work" on Windows 7?

Comment: What *precisely* doesn't work?

Comment: tell what output you get for which file permissions when you run the above code. Cant do anything without that.

Comment: methods canXXX always return true, even when should not.

Comment: Did you check your program hasn't extended rights ? Why do you say it should not return true ? Do you get an error later while reading or writing ?

Comment: Yes, for example I trying:   FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);   And it causes java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\test\write_to_queue2.bat (Access denied)

Comment: And it shouldn't return true beacuse I deny the reading permission

Answer (score 10):

It is hard to believe that the Java `File.canXxxx()` methods are *generally* broken on any flavour of Windows.

However, read [this Sun bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6203387) ... and weep.  The short answer is that it is a Windows bug, and Sun decided not to work around it.  (But the new Java 7 APIs *do* work ...)

FWIW, I maintain that it is BAD PRACTICE to try to check file access permissions like that.  It is better to simply attempt to use the file, and catch the exceptions if / when they occur.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6093037/139985 for my reasoning.  (And now we have another reason ...)

Comment: but they are, File.canExecute() return true, while executing file (.bat) in cmd return "Access denied"

Comment: I have tested the code in the link, and I found that in jdk 1.7.0_79 this bug is no more. When I set the file to cannot write and is hidden in Windows 10 Explorer, the code shows it's cannot be written and is hidden, as expected. So I think it's fixed in Java 7.

Comment: Unfortunately the referenced link to "why-is-it-easier-to-ask-forgiveness-than-permission-in-python-but-not-in-java" on stackoverflow has either been moved or removed.

Comment: It was deleted along with its parent question.  I'm asking the moderators to do something about that.

Answer (score 6):

I have done some tests on the NIO APIs (from Java 7) and they seem to work perfectly.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PermissionCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String filePath = args[0];
        Path p = Paths.get(filePath);

        if (Files.notExists(p))
            throw new FileNotFoundException();

        if (Files.isWritable(p))
            ...

        if (Files.isReadable(p))
            ...

        if (Files.isExecutable(p))
            ...
    }
}
```

JDKs: 1.7.0_25, 1.8.0_91

OS: Windows 7, 8 (64bit)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Java trust local files and untrust remote files by default and by design. So when testing, be aware of that what you can do in your computer at home, may be impossible in some remote drive of your company's server.

Second, when we check file permissions on remote drives, it's usually not enough just setting it in the Windows Explorer(<kbd>Property...</kbd> - <kbd>Read only</kbd>/<kbd>Hide</kbd>/<kbd>Archive</kbd>, etc. ). For example, my organization have other mechinisms to control both local and remote file permission, and even being Administrator of my PC cannot guarantee everything. Even if manually/programmatically you can change the permission of a file, if some other applications/group policy/etc forbids you to do so, the change may fail. (For example, `setReadable()` returns `false`, suggesting that it's not possible)For example, I can `execute` a `txt` file in a remote directory, meaning open it, but a `bat` file in the same directory is not executable, actually, in my case, I am required to ask my admin to gain more authority when I want to create a `bat` file. I think it might be that `bat` extension are forbidden. Because as user in some user group in Windows, your action and JVM run by you are limited by higher rules than JVM itself.  Correct me if I am wrong.

However, even if you might not be able to set the permisson of a file, now you can read them correctly in Java 7. Obviously after the bug report, Java guys had done something to fix the most of it. I am using `jdk 1.7.0_19`, and to test, I have done the following:

1. Set the property of a remote file, in Windows Explorer, to `Read Only` and `Hidden`.
2. Read it from Java, with code below (from the link of Stephen C and modified to see `setXxxxx()` methods can work).

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class FilePermissionTester {
       public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
           File file = new File("Y:\\some\\remote\\drive\\directoy\\xxxxx.txt");
           System.out.println( "exists:"  + file.exists() );
           System.out.println( "is file:"  + file.isFile() );
           System.out.println( "can read:" + file.canRead() );
           System.out.println( "can execute:" + file.canExecute() );
           System.out.println( "can write:" + file.canWrite() );
           System.out.println( "is hidden:" + file.isHidden() );

           System.out.println("change it to be unreadable, and it works? " + file.setReadable(false));
           System.out.println( "can read:" + file.canRead() );
           System.out.println("change it to be writable, and it works? " + file.setWritable(true));
           System.out.println( "can write:" + file.canWrite() );
           FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
           fileInputStream.read();
           fileInputStream.close();


       }

   }
   ```

I got:

```
exists:true
is file:true
can read:true
can execute:true
can write:false
is hidden:true
change it to be unreadable, and it works? false
can read:true
change it to be writable, and it works? true
can write:true
```

And now I can read this file, edit it and save it. Before changing the permission I was asked to <kbd>Save As..</kbd> when saving.

Note that the file is readable, and `setReadable(false)` returns `false`, and the file is still readble. JavaDoc says [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadable(boolean)) that `setReadable()` return `false` when user haven't permission to change the access premission, or when `readable` is already `false`, and the underlying system doesn't have implementation for this. Debugging into Java API doesn't provide much info, because the implementation are marked `native` and cannot see more. But I have the permission to change the writability, so that's something I don't understand.

But also note that there are more attributes out there that are not supported by `java.util.File`, like <strike>`setHidden()`</strike>. Maybe you can check other pacakges in `java.security`, like [AccessController](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html)?