# How to fix Java ProcessBuilder "Command Not Found" for Linux-based systems?

Tags: java, bash, shell, processbuilder, gnome-terminal

--- Specs ---
Operating System: Ubuntu-based Pop OS
OS Version: 22.04
Desktop Environment: default / GNOME
Used OS Shell(s): default / bash & sh
Programming Language: Java 8 / 17
Program Environment: all default IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition), Build #IC-223.8214.52, built on December 20, 2022
Program JDK: manually installed Amazon Corretto 8 / 17, also tried in-built IntelliJ OpenJDK 16 & 17 to no avail.

--- Background (in case this is relevant) ---
I am working on a java photo editing automation program for which I   need to perform actions such as opening a photo editing software. I'd    like a java robot to press Super_L/Meta_L/Windows_L to open the Ubuntu   launcher, then type in the photo editing software name and confirm.
In order to achieve a press of the Super_L-key through java, I figured   out that I would have to temporarily assign the Meta_L-Key to my   Super_L-key using "xmodmap -e ...".

--- Problem Description ---
While I could successfully implement the rest,
I am severely struggling with executing the "xmodmap" shell-command using java.
I did not manually set any aliases or environmental variables regarding xmodmap.
Outside of java, it does work using bash, sh and "gnome-terminal -- xmodmap ..."
and the command exists in /usr/bin/ as "xmodmap".
I did try reading the /usr/bin folder of the executing java process to find "xmodmap" missing from the list.
I assumed "xmodmap" were a shell-builtin, but apparently I was wrong?
How can I invoke this command (and others like it)?

--- Code Chunk ---

```
    private void temporarilyAssignMetaLKeyToWindowsKey() {
        // xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Meta_L"
        String cmd = "xmodmap -e \"keycode 133 = Meta_L\""; // does not work!
        //  cmd = "ls -alt /usr/bin |grep -i xm"; // works!
        try {
            // execute command
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/bash", "-c", cmd);
            processBuilder.inheritIO();
            System.out.println(processBuilder.command());
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            // print command output
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String output = null;
            while((output = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            // wait for command to finish
            process.waitFor();

            // close resources
            bufferedReader.close();
            process.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

--- Produced Result ---

> /usr/bin/bash: line 1: xmodmap: command not found

**Edit:**
Running "echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE" in terminal returns "x11" (xorg).

**Edit 2:**
Added program environment.

**Edit 3:**
xmodmap *before* applying modifications:
[image]
[image]
xmodmap *after* applying modifications:
[image]
[image]

**Edit 4:**
Sudo-ing the command does not change the outcome:

```
String cmd = "sudo /usr/bin/xmodmap -e \"keycode 133 = Meta_L\"";
// ...
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/bash", "-c", cmd); // /usr/bin/bash: line 1: sudo: command not found
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd); // java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sudo /usr/bin/xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Meta_L"": error=2, No such file or directory
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sudo /usr/bin/xmodmap", "-e", "keycode 133 = Meta_L"); // java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sudo /usr/bin/xmodmap": error=2, No such file or directory
```

**Edit 5:**

```
xmodmap -e "remove mod1 = Meta_L" && xmodmap -e "add mod4 = Meta_L" && xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Super_L"  

xmodmap -e "add mod4 = Super_L" && xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Meta_L" && xmodmap -e "add mod1 = Meta_L" && exit
```

these could also not be found, same error message

Thank you very much in advance!
Feel free to correct me (:

Comment: Use the absolute path `/usr/bin/xmodmap`

Comment: @Stewart Thank you for the quick response! If I do so I get "/usr/bin/bash: line 1: /usr/bin/xmodmap: No such file or directory".

Comment: And what happens when you do `which xmodmap` ?

Comment: @Stewart returns "/usr/bin/xmodmap"

Comment: Why `bash` to invoke `xmodmap`?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I was looking for a workaround, since only using `new ProcessBuilder("xmodmap ...")` leads to `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "xmodmap": error=2, No such file or directory`

Comment: Use absolute path and multiple strings:  `new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/xmodmap", "-e", "keycode 133 = Meta_L")` and you also simplify the quotes

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano ```ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/xmodmap", "-e", "keycode 133 = Meta_L");``` throws ```java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/xmodmap": error=2, No such file or directory```

Comment: Please execute the command in the terminal and post exactly what works

Comment: Also, if a modifier is currently assigned, it must first be cleared. See [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap)

Comment: How and where are you executing the java app?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I'm simply using IntelliJ to run the program (IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition) Build IC-223.8214.52 from Dec 20th 2022 - if that matters).

Comment: @g00se I added the terminal execution & responses. I don't believe I understand what you mean by _Also, if a modifier is currently assigned, it must first be cleared_, but I did not manually make any prior modifications using xmodmap. I am using it on a fresh, unmodified keymap table.

Comment: You need to use the *clear* option first - read the article I linked. Also please ensure you can do it at the command line first. xmodmap is *not* a shell built-in

Comment: Forgot to say - you need to use *add* finally too. See section 5.2

Comment: The error (error=2) shows that `/usr/bin/xmodmap` is not found or cannot be executed, that's the first issue, then clearing modifiers and other stuff may come.

Comment: Do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/37070496/236465 with `/usr/bin/xmodmap` before trying `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: Incidentally the "command not found" thing is an error message thrown up by xmodmap when the syntax is wrong

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano The "FileNotFound" exception is thrown immediately for "/usr/bin/xmodmap".

Comment: @g00se I do not want to configure the keymap at the CLI first, the project is supposed to be entirely automated. FYI: bash scripts called through java are neglected just as well as calling the command directly due to xmodmap seemingly missing completely for the java shell. I could probably let a bash script run the xmodmap configuration and the java program, however that would only circumvent the issue, not solve it.

Comment: I'm aware that you want automation. xmodmap will be present most anywhere. It's certainly present in PopOs! - I just checked

Comment: @g00se So you are proposing I should try to clear Meta_L & Super_L manually, then run & add the reassignment via java?

Comment: What I'm proposing is that you first create a script. Get your clear, add, setting OK in that. Run it at the command line. It can be *one* xmodmap command with three expressions, potentially. Doing it in Java should then be trivial.

Comment: @g00se Alright, I sorta did that to no avail, same error message of "no such file or directory"

Comment: Please show the commands in your script that ran successfully and did what you wanted it to do

Comment: This is not really a Java question. You should be asking experienced X people as I too am unfamiliar with xmodmap

Comment: @g00se I fiddled around with a few, all of which worked (in console, i.e.), e.g. ```xmodmap -e "remove mod1 = Meta_L" && xmodmap -e "add mod4 = Meta_L" && xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Super_L"```   and 
```xmodmap -e "add mod4 = Super_L" && xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Meta_L" && xmodmap -e "add mod1 = Meta_L" && exit```, but at the end of the day no matter the syntax & structure, none of em work directly in java. got any recommendations where to start regarding X-specialists?

Comment: I can do some testing myself though I have to admit, somewhat ashamedly, when I tried this before, I got myself into a mess and had to restart X ;) One thing you can do, with a working one, is try chaining expressions instead of using &&. That will make it easier in `ProcessBuilder`